# Предварительная загрузка аудио в JS

Tags: javascript, html, аудио

Возник вопрос, как заставить браузер загрузить в память все звуки, которые будут воспроизводиться на странице, чтобы снизить задержку между событием и проигрыванием.
Попробовал загрузить все в переменную при загрузке страницы, но не заметил, чтобы задержка снизилась:

```
const sounds = [];
for(i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    let aud = new Audio(names[i]);
    //audio.src = names[i];
    sounds.push(aud);
}

//Вызываем:
sounds[0].play();
```

Comment: Попробуйте выставить значение `preload="auto"`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#attr-preload

Comment: Пробовал, но изменений не заметил

Comment: Для начала строчку `sounds.push(aud);` изменить так: 
`sounds[i] = new Audio(names[i]);` 
  
так работать будет быстрее, а строку `let aud = new Audio(names[i]);` тогда убрать вообще.

Comment: Ещё решение зависит от того, должны ли звуки между собой накладываться. Если нет, то достаточно будет одного элемента аудио с загруженным аудиофайлом, содержащим все звуки по очереди.

Comment: Накладываться не должны. А как я из одного файла буду получать необходимые кусочки и воспроизводить их?

Comment: При выборе звука нужно будет свойству **audio.currentTime** присваивать место начала воспроизведения этого звука в файле (на какой секунде, включая дробную часть, если она есть) и ещё задавать длительность этого звука в **setTimeout()** для окончания воспроизведения файла: `setTimeout(function(){audio.pause()}, 3000);` если скажем он длится 3 сек.